# Deleting items from ListView in Android (mysql)

Tags: android, mysql, listview

im quite new in Android programming and i really need your help. I have items inside my listview and all of it are saved in mysql. I want to delete a specific row by clicking on it. My problem is that my items are not deleted after hitting the "delete item". The "delete item" came from context menu and will popout if i longclick the said item. I know that there is already a thread quite similar to mine but the solutions provided does not solve my problem.

Here are the relevant codes. Hoping that you guys might help me.

**LIST ACTIVITY**

```
public class ScheduleListActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    SchedDbHelper schedDbHelper;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule_list);

        listView =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
        schedDbHelper = new SchedDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = schedDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = schedDbHelper.getInformations(sqLiteDatabase);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{

                String day,time,amount;
                day = cursor.getString(0);
                time = cursor.getString(1);
                amount = cursor.getString(2);
                DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(day,time,amount);
                listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);
                registerForContextMenu(listView);

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_context_menu, menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.delete_id:


                String position = String.valueOf(info.position);
                schedDbHelper = new SchedDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
                sqLiteDatabase = schedDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                schedDbHelper.deleteinformation(position, sqLiteDatabase);

                Object toRemove = listDataAdapter.getItem(info.position);
                listDataAdapter.remove(toRemove);
                listDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Deleted" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }

    }


}
```

**SchedDBHELPER**

```
public class SchedDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SCHEDINFO.DB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSIONS = 1;
    private static final String CREATE_QUERY =
    "CREATE TABLE "+ScheduleContract.NewSchedInfo.TABLE_NAME+"("+ ScheduleContract.NewSchedInfo.SCHED_DAY+" TEXT,"+
            ScheduleContract.NewSchedInfo.SCHED_TIME+" TEXT,"+ ScheduleContract.NewSchedInfo.SCHED_AMOUNT+" TEXT);";

    public SchedDbHelper(Context context)
    {

     super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSIONS);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "Database created / opened... ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "Table created... ");

    }

    public void addInformations(String day, String time, String amount, SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ScheduleContract.NewSchedInfo.SCHED_DAY, day);
        contentValues.put(ScheduleContract.NewSchedInfo.SCHED_TIME, time);
        contentValues.put(ScheduleContract.NewSchedInfo.SCHED_AMOUNT, amount);
        db.insert(ScheduleContract.NewSchedInfo.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "One row inserted... ");

    }

    public Cursor getInformations(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        Cursor cursor;
        String[] projections = {ScheduleContract.NewSchedInfo.SCHED_DAY, ScheduleContract.NewSchedInfo.SCHED_TIME,
                ScheduleContract.NewSchedInfo.SCHED_AMOUNT};
       cursor = db.query(ScheduleContract.NewSchedInfo.TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }

    public void deleteinformation(String position, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)

  {
      String table = ScheduleContract.NewSchedInfo.TABLE_NAME;
      String key = ScheduleContract.NewSchedInfo.SCHED_DAY;
      String[] whereargs = {position};
      sqLiteDatabase.delete(table,key + "=?", whereargs);
  }
```

**LIST DATA ADAPTER**

```
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List list = new ArrayList();

    public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {

        super(context, resource);
    }

    static class LayoutHandler
    {
        TextView DAY,TIME,AMOUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Object object) {
        super.remove(object);
        list.remove(object);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return list.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return list.get(position);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.DAY = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_day);
            layoutHandler.TIME = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_time);
            layoutHandler.AMOUNT = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_amount);
            row.setTag(layoutHandler);
        }
        else
        {
            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();

        }
             DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider)this.getItem(position);
             layoutHandler.DAY.setText(dataProvider.getDay().toString());
             layoutHandler.TIME.setText(dataProvider.getTime().toString());
             layoutHandler.AMOUNT.setText(dataProvider.getAmount().toString());

             return row;

    }
}
```

Comment: you are passing the position as table id key....I guess that´s not what you need. Please show us how you implemented your database..

Comment: also you are not refreshing your list after deleting item so your deleted data will be available in modal

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Thank you for replying I already edited my post hope you can understand it better. I placed my entire code for List activity, dbhelper and my listadapter. Hope you can help me.

Comment: @VivekMishra Thank you for replying ill try refreshing it after i get the code in deleting hope you can help me to do it.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs pls still not solved can you help me. i just dont understand what data should i pass. T_T

Comment: you are comparing `ScheduleContract.NewSchedInfo.SCHED_DAY;` as key in your delete method so you need to pass the day to the delete method.

Comment: I guess you have too much misunderstandings here. The best way to delete or change some rows is to add an id as the first column and retrieve it everytime you want to manupulate or delete a row. This is done via the statement `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` in your create table statement. But this is too much here, I can only recommend to read this good tutorial and start again with your database implementation:http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/